# Google Apps Script [Spreadsheet Date]

Tags: google-apps-script

I have 2 columns
'StartDate' and 'EndDate'

Is it possible to do validation to check that 'EndDate' cannot be earlier than 'StartDate', vice versa?
I don't know if validation is to be done on the spreadsheet itself, or through script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily do it using the Spreadsheet built-in data validation feature (menu Data > Validation). Using a "Custom Formula" validation, and simply typing `=B1>A1` (assuming your 2 columns are the 1st 2).

Or do it in a script using the `onEdit` trigger, which is also easy, but not as much as the above.

--edit

If you also have to check if the cell is a Date, you could use the following formula as data validation:

```
=AND(DateValue(B1),B1>A1)
```

It would look like this using an `onEdit` trigger:

```js
function onEdit() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  if( s.getName() !== 'Sheet1' ) return; //check if it's the sheet we want to monitor
  var r = s.getActiveRange();
  if( r.getColumn() !== 2 ) return; //check if it's the column we're interested
  var v = r.getValue();
  if( typeof v !== 'object' ) {
    r.setValue('');
    return SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Enter a valid date!');
  }
  var vA = r.offset(0, -1).getValue();
  if( typeof vA === 'object' ) {
    if( vA.getTime() >= v.getTime() ) {
      r.setValue('');
      return SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Enter a date bigger than start date!');
    }
  } //what to do if there is no date in column A?
}
```

Note that this code does not check if the start date is changed, and therefore it can be changed afterwards to a value greater than the end date. But if you go with this code solution you should be able to take it from here.

Comment: Thank you! Didn't know it's that easy!

Comment: Hi, I already have a validation that makes sure the date is a valid date. There isn't an option to add another new rule. How can it be done via onEdit trigger?

Comment: thanks once again!

For =B1>A1, how do i check with the entire column instead of just one cell?

Comment: Setup for one cell, then copy and paste for the following. It'll auto-update the references.

Answer (score 0):

You could also convert the dates to integers and compare the values. if(int(enddate-startdate<0,do something,do something else)